# Immortal NPC encountered on Riften dragon bounty quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was on the miscellaneous quest to kill the dragon up for bounty in Riften, fighting a dragon, when all of a sudden I started to get attacked by a witch, some random soldier NPCs, and a spriggen, all at once. I eventually managed to dispatch the dragon and most of the attackers, but there was a single soldier NPC who must clearly be essential because he absolutely would not die, even though he continued to attack. He would go down once all of his health was out like the followers do, then get back up and continue to attack. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Who the heck is this guy?

Comment: This happens quite often in the camps of the opposing faction (if you've chosen), I believe they're the npc that hands out quests that allow you to progress on the chosen faction path.

Comment: did he have a name?

Comment: I figured out who he is - it was Vilkas. I must have accidentally hit him with some magic or something while I was fighting the dragon and got him hostile. Do NPCs eventually 'forgive and forget', or am I screwed out of doing Companion stuff now?

Comment: @Helena Since you're question has morphed, you might want to edit it so that it is clear that you're now interested not in why someone would be immortal, but how you can make him stop being hostile.

Answer (score 2):

Sheathe your weapon in front of the NPC, If they accept the yield they will return to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Your safest bet is to use some Calming magic to stop them from hitting you, then fast travel away. I've heard mixed reports on whether they settle down and let you be after that, or if they will still attack on sight. Rule of thumb is typically tied to your bounty in that hold, though.